# Has URL Mappings changed in Grails 1.3.7?

Tags: grails

**The situation:**

Say I have an example controller called AccountController with some actions of show, edit and update.

In the Grails URL Mappings I am trying to map by method type e.g. GET POST etc etc

Then I have a link that points to the controllers corresponding action like so:

```
<g:link controller="account" action="edit">Edit my account link</g:link>
```

**with the mappings of:**

```
"/profile"      (controller: "account", action: "show")
"/profile/edit" (controller: "account", action: [GET: "edit", POST: "update"])
```

the problem here is the link that is generated should be using the mappings for lookups and making it look like so **"/profile/edit"** in the generated html page but instead the page has **"/account/edit"** which according to the mappings don't exist so just causes an error when clicked.

**I have even tried the alternative syntax of:**

```
"/profile/edit" (controller: "account") { action = [GET: "edit", POST: "update"] }
```

but it still points to a url mapping that does not exist.

Is this a bug or just me having a bad day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this (reverse URL mappings with HTTP methods) was working in previous versions of Grails, but I have reproduced your problem here in 1.3.7 and the only solution I came up with was to use [named URL mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings). Using it, your tag would be:

```
<g:link controller="account" action="edit" mapping="profileEditing">
    Edit my account link
</g:link>
```

and the edit mapping would be:

```
name profileEditing: "/profile/edit" (controller: "account") {
    action = [GET: "edit", POST: "update"]
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for that. It most certainly did work with earlier versions. On page 152 of "The Definitive Guide to Grails by Graeme Rocher" they show the second method with a closure doing HTTP method mappings.